VS Code Proxy Setting Configuration
How can i set http/https proxy and no proxy in VS code only. I've tried vs code --> settings --> proxy but no matter what i set it always fails to connect.
tried to set via vs code --> settings -- > proxy
Http: Proxy
The proxy setting to use. If not set, will be inherited from the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables.

It sounds like you've found the right setting, so "it always fails to connect" is likely an issue with how you're trying to use the proxy.
